# Techniques for debugging ARM deployment scripts

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Im learning ARM deployment scripts and i want to know if there are maybe debug tools and techniques im not familiar with. Mostly when i release i get good feedback from the logging error messages but know i have a larger than im used to deployment script and i get three errors at the same time but no information on what part of the script they are refering to! Is there some more information, lgging features or tools im not aware of?

[Here is the ARM script](https://pastebin.com/ZDWjxUek)

This is what the errors look like atm:

```
    2020-03-29T11:05:22.8089784Z The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\_Servicebus build\drop\ApimArmDeploy.json' is 'utf-8'
2020-03-29T11:05:22.8133243Z The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\_Servicebus build\drop\ApimArmDeploy-Parameters.json' is 'utf-8'
2020-03-29T11:05:23.0663551Z Starting template validation.
2020-03-29T11:05:23.0677286Z Deployment name is ApimArmDeploy-20200329-110523-e3d8
2020-03-29T11:05:23.6326816Z Template deployment validation was completed successfully.
2020-03-29T11:05:23.6328017Z Starting Deployment.
2020-03-29T11:05:23.6329586Z Deployment name is ApimArmDeploy-20200329-110523-e3d8
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9249116Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9299184Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9309993Z ##[error]Details:
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9312243Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ValidationError",
    "message": "One or more fields contain incorrect values:",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "ValidationError",
        "target": "representation",
        "message": "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
      }
    ]
  }
}
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9330396Z ##[error]Conflict: {
  "error": {
    "code": "Conflict",
    "message": "System.InvalidOperationException: Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration. Please change Environment variable AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType value to 'Files'. For more info, visit https://aka.ms/funcsecrets\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetKeyObjectFromFile>d__9`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Functions\\FunctionManager.cs:line 141\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetFunctionSecretsAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Functions\\FunctionManager.cs:line 220\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Functions.FunctionController.<GetSecrets>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Functions\\FunctionController.cs:line 141"
  }
}
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9361241Z ##[error]NotFound: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/tostore-apim' under resource group 'INT001-TestOrderStore-Cert' was not found."
  }
}
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9365605Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
2020-03-29T11:05:54.9371498Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure Deployment: APIM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's '[Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools)' extension for VS Code provides a level of syntax highlighting which can help draw your attention to errors in your ARM templates.

It can also be helpful to set the `System.Debug` variable to `true` on your build/release pipeline which provides verbose logging output:

[image]

Comment: Great advice! Very handy. I hope you dont mind a follow up. Is there anyway i can test expressions and se what they return before deploying? Its so hard to troubleshoot when i have to deploy each time.

Comment: I don't have much gold for you I'm afraid, but I guess to shorten the feed back loop you could deploy from your local machine using the 'az group deployment create' task from the Azure CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest